# Create Keyboard "Extension" like Windows 8 Metro IE

Tags: javascript, windows-8, keyboard, windows-runtime, winjs

In Windows 8 Metro Style IE, if you click on the address bar, there will be "bookmark" tiles show up on the top of the address bar. If you are on a touch device, the tiles will show up above the soft keyboard.

I wonder how to I can do similar things in my own app.

Image can be found here. http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/f1/f32/11632d1353517665-ie10-metro-favorites-screenshot-2-.png

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the [`Showing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.showing.aspx) and [`Hiding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.hiding.aspx) events on `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane`. The [`InputPaneVisibilityEvent.OccludedRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpanevisibilityeventargs.occludedrect.aspx) tells you what part of the screen the keyboard is covering up. You can then place your tiles immediately above it.

The "[Responding to the appearance of the on-screen keyboard](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Keyboard-Events-Sample-866ba41c)" sample walks you through it.